# Was the kiss ever acknowledged?

Tags: star-wars

In Star Wars Episode V, I believe, Leia kisses Luke out of spite for Han.

Once they find out they are siblings (Luke and Leia), is that kiss they shared ever acknowledged in other media (like novels or comics, etc.)?

Comment: That's not the only kiss they share.

Comment: Relevant: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IPAGXyFvrs

Comment: I have some vague recollection of possible acknowledgement in whichever book had Han finally propose to Leia (the name escapes me at the moment). It's been >10 years since I read it though so not sure.

Comment: I seem to remember Leia making a comment to someone who was looking for a mate that Luke was a pretty good kisser.

Comment: @DVK "The Courtship of Princess Leia"? Or maybe not until the sequel, it's been a while and my books aren't here.

Comment: @Kevin - correct.

Comment: I have access to the books but I cannot seem to find anything in _The Courtship of Princess Leia_. Does anyone else remember anymore details?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well after their sibling relationship was revealed, I'm sure they secretely felt awkward, but It's not like they slept together! Siblings seperated at birth who meet each other for the first time are often sexually attracted, due to humans tendency to look for mates that are similar in apperance to one another. Also being twins they probably felt very similar. To my knowledge, outside Robot Chicken, Luke never acknowledged the kiss.

Comment: This assumes that the cultures they were raised in (Tatooine and Aldaraan) or the "common" galactic culture consider incest wrong.  Not all cultures do.  To keep the royal bloodlines pure, the Inca Emperor's primary wife was his sister and only one of their sons (who now had a Mother/Aunt and Father/Uncle) could be the Emperor.  And in Amish communities there are many genetic defects because there are so many intermarriages.  (While I don't think the Amish allow brother-sister relationships, it's still an example of how even on Earth there aren't universal standards on incest.)

Comment: also remember that a kiss doesn't incest make.

Comment: @TangoOversway: Pretty much all monarchies and other highly classist societies' elites have historically practiced incest. This is true of the Greeks, Egyptians, and the European monarchies. That's why so many royal families have really high incidences of congenital illness (e.g. hemophilia, schizophrenia, and general physical abnormalities). This is partly to do with classist prejudices (e.g. not wanting to dilute the bloodline; royalty are living gods, so only another family member is worthy of marrying them; etc.), but sibling marriages are also arranged to keep power within the family.

Comment: However, while it's true that siblings separated at birth are often sexually attracted to one another when they're reunited later on, there's evidence that we've evolved to seek out dissimilarity rather than similarity in a mate. The human equivalent of pheromones seems to help us find a mate who is genetically dissimilar to us via the Major Histocompatibility Complex--creating couples with heterogeneous immune systems, which means their offspring will inherit a broader set of natural immunities.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté: Yes, you're right.  My main point is that we're assuming that their cultures share this taboo with prevalent Western culture.  I felt that I should include a few examples to back it up.

Comment: So the more different two people's MHCs are, the more appealing they will find eachother's scent. OTOH, if you're closely genetically related to another person (e.g. a sibling), then they're likely to have a very similar MHC to yourself, and their natural scent will be more repulsive to you.

Comment: @Tango incest ftw!

Comment: @MishaRosnach There's disagreement on MHC's effect on attraction (this is one study that supports the theory: http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/cgi/pmidlookup?view=long&pmid=18700206), but it's not something that can be usefully implemented in perfumes. Even if the consumer sent in a DNA sample from their desired partner and the perfumer had a library of various LHA profiles to find a match against, it'd be difficult to synthesize the complex mixture that forms the body scent of someone with complimentary MHC.

Answer (score 2):

Since the "kiss" was more a dare, likely Luke and Leia could easily accept any unintentional incestuous miscues as done out of ignorance once they knew they were twin brother and sister.  It would give them closure as to WHY they had feelings for each other and a strong sense of familiarity.  "I know.  Somehow...I've always known."